# Error when trying to send HTML email on event onActivateUser

Tags: plugin-development, emails, events

**Background:**

I'm working on a site that has frontend registration with some custom fields. The client would like to have a notification email whenever someone activates their account, containing the info on that user (so name, email and the custom fields).

---

**Issue at hand:**

For some reason, I'm getting the following error when I try to send an HTML email on the 'onActivateUser':

> Unable to find the template “_emails/customer-service-notification”.

If however I try to send a plain text email, it all goes without problem.

I'd prefer to send out an HTML email so I'd like to resolve this.

---

**What I already tried:**

- Triggering the service function in another way (via custom controller action) sends the html email just fine
- Sending the mail by just setting the content as string in the function works just fine

---

**Code**:

*Main plugin file - init function*

```
craft()->on('users.onActivateUser', function (Event $event){
    $user = $event->params['user'];
    craft()->plugin_customerServiceNotification->sendNotificationMail($user);
});
```

*customerServiceNotification*

```
public function sendNotificationMail(UserModel $user){
    $mailer = craft()->email;
    $mailToBeSent = new EmailModel();

    $mailToBeSent->subject = Craft::t('Nieuwe gebruiker geregistreerd');
    $mailToBeSent->fromName = 'xyz';
    $mailToBeSent->sender = 'noreply@xyz.be';

    $mailToBeSent->toEmail = 'xyz@xyz.be';

    $content = craft()->templates->render(
        '_emails/customer-service-notification',
        [
            'userInfo' => [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'name' => $user->fullName,
            ],
        ]
    );
    $mailToBeSent->htmlBody = $content;

    $mailer->sendEmail($mailToBeSent);
}
```

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Try adding a `craft()->templates->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::Site);` line before the call to `craft()->templates->render()`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks a lot! If you want to add it as answer, than I'll make sure to accept it as well :)

Comment: No problem and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `sendNotificationEmail()` to this should fix it for you:

```
public function sendNotificationMail(UserModel $user) {
    $mailer = craft()->email;
    $mailToBeSent = new EmailModel();

    $mailToBeSent->subject = Craft::t('Nieuwe gebruiker geregistreerd');
    $mailToBeSent->fromName = 'xyz';
    $mailToBeSent->sender = 'noreply@xyz.be';

    $mailToBeSent->toEmail = 'xyz@xyz.be';

    $originalTemplateMode = craft()->templates->getTemplateMode();
    craft()->template->setTemplateMode(TemplateMode::Site);

    $content = craft()->templates->render(
        '_emails/customer-service-notification',
        [
            'userInfo' => [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'name' => $user->fullName,
            ],
        ]
    );

    $mailToBeSent->htmlBody = $content;
    $mailer->sendEmail($mailToBeSent);

    craft()->templates->setTemplateMode($originalTemplateMode);
}
```